# Using c2hs on Windows

Tags: haskell, ffi, c2hs

I'm trying to use the libxml-enumerator package on Windows, which (ultimately) needs to use c2hs. When trying to build the relevant package, I get the seemingly infamous "does not exist" error from c2hs. This seems to be related to not having GCC installed, but this seems a list strange, since I've added Haskell's copy of gcc.exe to my path.

Does anyone know how to defeat this bug?

Comment: Hi Michael, what's the actual error message?

Except for updates to Platform packages, which I think can be be re-built with the minimal set of MinGW tools distributed with GHC, using a proper installation of MinGW and MSys usually saves a lot of frustration for bindings. Although c2hs is a FFI tool rather than a binding, I'd still head straight to MinGW and MSys if it were me.

Comment: OK, installing the full-blown MinGW seems to have gotten ridden of the "does not exist" error, thank you. I hadn't realized it was expecting a different GCC than the one bundled with GHC. Now I get to battle through all the other joys of Windows development ;).

Comment: I'm not sure that its a different GCC so much, just that with MinGW + MSys installed there's the whole compiler suite present (make, autoconfig, all the system headers and static libraries etc.). The MinGW that is bundled with GHC contains just enough for GHC's needs - at least gcc, the binutils, some more but not a lot.

Comment: Snoyman: You should post an answer and mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is to install MinGW by itself and not rely on the MinGW included with GHC. Hope this helps someone in the future.